# CSV Field Mapping GUI

Tags: php, csv

I need to add one of these to a project.  Is there an an open source PHP project made for this?  Don't want to reinvent the wheel.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possible implementations of what you ask for include

- [Quick CSV import with visual mapping](http://i1t2b3.com/2009/01/14/quick-csv-import-with-mapping/)

  This a full implementation with a visual mapping, though it isn't themed like your picture. An example of usage is avaliable [here](http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/how-to-import-csv-file-in-your-php-application/)
- [jQuery csv2table](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/csv2table)

  This is a partial implementation it converts csv to a html table data. The remaining part would be to convert the generated table to SQL with a visual mapping

The following items are PHP partial implementations that map  csv to sql without providing a visual mapping to the user.

- [PHP csv2sql](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2894-PHP-Convert-CSV-files-into-SQL-INSERT-statements.html)
- [PHP FileImporter](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4998-PHP-Import-data-from-CSV-files-into-a-MySQL-database.html)
- [PHP csv2db](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2503-PHP-Import-data-from-a-CSV-file-into-a-database.html)
- [PHP csv-importer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4411-PHP-Import-data-from-a-CSV-file-into-a-MySQL-table.html)
- [PHP csv2mysql](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/842-PHP-convert-fields-in-a-csv-into-SQL.html)
- [PHP adv_csv](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5073-PHP-Export-and-import-data-in-CSV-from-HTML-or-MySQL.html)
- [PHP csv](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/827-PHP-A-class-for-import-comma-separated-and-fixed-files.html)

Comment: The example here: http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/how-to-import-csv-file-in-your-php-application/  Is just great.  Read over all of the code and gave it a test drive.  Thanks!  Saved me some hours of unnecessary work!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes reinventing the wheel is good, you get what you need, and what you need only

This seems easy, first you need a csv kinda parser, but that's just too easy you can do something like:

Your task may be break down in:

1.- Import the csv :
(Build an upload form, handle file extension validation.

2.- Store the csv somewhere temporarily
(Store file, probably with hash instead of name so no conflicts exist

3.- Parse the csv.
(http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php will be your friend)

4.- Two input fields, one for the parsed files and one for your map, use some sessions/javascript fancyness for adding the right columns on the fly

5.- Then store the mapped columns to real csv values.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.  Yes those are the steps involved.  I have offered 50 pts of reputation to find out if robust jQuery/PHP has already been written NOT because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - "This is not an answer to the question". Maybe not, but be nice all the same `:)`